# sed command to delete variable number of lines

Tags: shell, sed

To delete the first 10 lines from a text file, the following command is used:

```
sed -i -e "1,10d" filename
```

what if I want to delete n number of lines, where n is a variable. i.e.
I am using following but getting errors, please correct me.

n=10

```
sed -i -e "1,$n{d}" filename
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable syntax is wrong. A variable is dereferenced as `${n}`. Hence, try

```
sed -i -e "1,${n}d" filename
```

Comment: And yet, Syed's command *should* have worked.  It works for me.  I wonder what went wrong.

Comment: @Scott Huh, yeah, good point. Yes, it works for me too. And you are right… although it makes little sense to use this construct, it should work.

Comment: For the record, @Scott, BSD sed (which is also on Macs) won't accept a `}` directly after a command—there needs to be a `;` first.  But BSD sed won't accept a `-i` flag without an argument...oh.  I figured it out.

Comment: @SyedMoez, did you have a backup file called `filename-e` mysteriously appear when you ran the command given in this answer?

Comment: @Wildcard: Happy New Year.  OK, this is fun. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) says “The <right-brace> shall be preceded by a <newline> or <semicolon> (before any optional <blank> characters preceding the <right-brace>).”  So, assuming you’re right (which I can’t test right now, but I trust you), BSD sed is POSIX compliant.  But the original command in the question (`sed ` `-i ` `-e "1,$n{d}" ` *`filename`*) works in GNU sed ***even if you add the* `--posix` *option!***

Comment: @Scott well, POSIX doesn’t mandate that that version be rejected.  Or does it?

Comment: @Wildcard: In specification language, “shall” is equivalent to “must”.  The spec says that blanks may *optionally* appear before the right brace.  If it meant that the newline or semicolon was optional, it would have said “The <right-brace> ***may*** be preceded by a <newline> or <semicolon>”.

Comment: @Scott but that requirement is addressed to authors of Sed scripts, not Sed developers.  The command above is not POSIX-compliant itself, but POSIX-compliant implementations of Sed don’t *have* to throw an error about it.